# How to Uninstall XPages Extension Library

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I want to make a `fresh` XPages Extension Library v15 installation. So I want to remove former v14 version completely. But I have not found any description how to make an uninstallation.

Is that not intended ?

Answer (score 2):

Open `File / Application / Application Management...` and uninstall ExtLib components:

[image]

If you installed your ExtLib with an updatesite.nsf then you can uninstall ExtLib with "Disable Features" there alternatively.

[image]

Comment: When I assume this correct, then this is a way to disable or uninstall certain features of a library. Is there also a way to remove a complete library without any complicated steps ?

Comment: In the update site, you can use the menu option `Actions -> Delete All Content`. This will remove the content completely, rather than disabling it. However, if you left v14 installed and installed v15 as well, there would be no problem as the server or designer automatically uses the most recent version it detects and would ignore v14

Comment: @Brian - I am very confused about the terminology and different ways IBM uses to install an ExtLib. Recommendations in all directions. This way for the Designer, the other way for prviewing, third way for the server and another time manually by copy paste in the file system. There is no current and definite Installl tutorial from IBM for all cases. Actually one needs a personal Install-IT-Admin to make everything correct.  Frustrating ....

Comment: @Brian - Sorry I forgot to ask: Where do I have to go to see the menu option `Action -> ...` ?

Comment: When you open the update site nsf, the option should be in the menu of the Notes Client

Comment: It's the database you installed ExtLib with. It looks like my second picture.

Comment: You may want to read more about update sites here: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/inst_creatingandusingannsfbasedupdatesite_t.dita